# Relationships For Data Model Concept

Tags: mysql, database

I'm a newbie in SQL and I'm having trouble figuring out what relationships to use for my tables. Basically I'm coding a website in PHP that is connected to a database where pre-existing customers can place an order.

**Requirements for the database**:

- Record a list hand cream products and sales
- Record inventory levels for all products
- Clients
- Sales of each product per customer

Right now I'm thinking of using 4 tables:

- Customer
- Sales
- Inventory
- and some sort of connecting table.

I have a pretty good idea of the fields I will use for the tables, but I'm having a really hard time wrapping my head around what the relationships between the tables would be.

Edit:

[image: Data model]

Comment: If your customers can buy products you need Products, Customers, Orders, OrdersDetail. The relations will be Orders, Customers, Orders OrdersDetail and Products OrdersDetails I suggest you to check online and find a copy of one of the oldest sample databases in internet history, the Northwind traders, Search it on google and you will be able to find it in many format. It is a very good example of relational db similar to what you want to do in your project

Comment: What is the actual SQL flavor? T-SQL or MySQL?

Comment: Which platform are you using -- sql-server or mysql -- you can't be using both -- if you mean generic then they both should be removed.  I'll do that.

Comment: I'm using MySQL, I changed the tags, thanks.

Comment: You are headed the right direction. Consider splitting "Sales" into "Sales_Header" and "Sales_Line" or "Orders" and "Order_Details" as @Sabrina_cs suggests since an order will be made of multiple lines, this is necessary to be properly normalized. As for relationships:  `Sales_Header` will have your `customer_id` in it. `Order_Line` will contain the `order_header_id`. `Inventory` can hang out by itself in it's most simple set up.

Comment: I added a picture of my general idea now.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

As per your requirements:

1. Recording a list of products and its sales. For this you would need a `Product` table with each product as a separate row, an `Order` table where you would store each order placement that can consist of many products, thus showing a need for junction table `Order_Product` or however you call it (OrderDetails in your picutre). The relations are Product and Order tables connected with Order_Product with a 1:N relationship (this is an implementation of N:N relationship between Order and Product). This allows you to have an order with multiple products and a product that can appear in multiple orders
2. Record inventory levels for all products. For this you could use existing `Product` table to keep the track of current storage amount.
3. Clients. That would require another table, `Customer` which would be in 1:N relationship with `Order` since one client can place many orders, but one order is connected to exactly one customer.
4. Sales of each product per customer. This is basically an SQL query that you could achieve with this database model.

Good to know:

- Does the company want to keep track of their orders of replenishment goods being sold to customers? Or is it only a CRM?
- Your database model, as long as it's a relational model is not vendor specific. This means that your model wouldn't change if you ever with to switch to SQL Server, or any other RDBMS.
- Why creating junction table `Order_Product` is considered good practice? It avoids data redundancy, and remember - relational databases are optimized to work on multiple tables fast.
- Creating indexes especially in your junction table will speed up the execution of your queries a lot. It seems like this would be the core table to be queried in your model.

Comment: Thank you! I think I have enough to start now.

Comment: Glad I could be of some help :-)